# I have added a new file type, such as bmp, in SharePoint 2013 search admin. I cannot search by filetype:bmp.

Tags: sharepoint-search

I have done the index-reset and full crawl. it still doesn't work. anybody has any ideas or how to trouble shooting? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query to `FileExtension=bmp`.

Comment: no, it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is the exact name of the file?